# Attempting to re-install ubuntu results in blank gray screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, usb

I just bought a used Dell Inspiron notebook with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I'd like to re-install it, but I'm running into some strange errors.

Here are the steps I took:

1.) Followed the steps on [the official Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) to create a bootable stick.

2.) Inserted the stick and turned on the computer

3.) The computer didn't automatically sense the stick, so I had to press f12 to get to the boot menu.

4.) Selected "usb storage device"

5.) Under the boot stick menu, selected "install ubuntu"

After that, this blank gray screen with the Ubuntu tool bar at the top comes up. I can't use the mouse or do anything else.

[image]

I tried again with a different boot stick, but with the same results. The native Ubuntu installation seems to work fine.

Has anyone else ever run into something like this?

Comment: I think the more interesting question to ask would be How to solve it, if of cause you actually want to solve it. As mentioned in another question, you need to try booting with the `nomodeset` option, and also, add the ouput of `lspci -nnk` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What GPU you have? The missing driver could possibly cause this... Boot with the mentioned `nomodeset` from Grub (select kernel, hit <kbd>e</kbd>, write at the end of the first line, hit <kbd>Boot</kbd>!)

See details [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132&p=10069997#post10069997), and feel free to comment, if you need assistance.